# Php phalcon Internal Server Error 500 Xampp

Tags: php, phalcon

Last two days I spent searching solution. I am very new on web programming especially with frameworks. I dont really know htaccess structure or server configuration. I red that I have to change Allowoverride none to all but in my httpd-vhosts.conf I do not see anything similar to this. Could someone explain more clearly what I should do?

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common 
##</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

All Your code is `commented`. Remove `#`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common 
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make entry for `ServerName` in your Sytem `HOSTS` file

Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` this file and add entry

```
127.0.0.1    dummy-host2.example.com
```

Or Whatever your host name is

Comment: Host file in System32? which Server name dummy-host or host 2? maybe both?

Comment: Done,  now Error 404 appears. I got everything with folders like here 
http://www.phalcon.pl/forum/tutoriale/hello-world/

Comment: Do You have any files in the directory defined above `F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com` or `F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com` Whichever you are visiting?. Also provide a screenshot of the error.

Comment: No I do not have. I got folder called phalcon so I will change names for phalcon. 127.0.0.1 phalcon. I got more projects. Can I write there just htdocs folder? I guess that every single name of folder in htdocs I should write to HOSTS file?

Comment: Directory structure need to as you defined in your `virtualHost` file. So when you visit `dummy-host2.example.com` it will load files from this `F:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com`

Comment: Ok theory is clear. I changed to phalcon because it is the name of the folder which i am visiting but still 404 error appears. Maybe I did not do that correctly? 

http://pastebin.com/L22z2EMy

Comment: Make sure to restart `apache` after updating `virtualHost` file and did you made the entry for `phalcon` in System `HOSTS` file. also provide screenshots of your error and update question with you update changes/code/screenshots

Comment: I am 100%  sure that I restarted apache. Still the same error. 
Httpd file now : http://pastebin.com/GsqbqfLA
Hosts file now: http://pastebin.com/1NPt4A9M
Error : http://imgur.com/NL6nhA4
Path: http://imgur.com/I0gLZ36

Comment: You are accessing `phalcon` the wrong way you don't have to access it through `localhost` thats the benefit of the `VirtualHost`. Access you `phalcon` directory via `http://phalcon`. If you still not able to access it then access `http://localhost` are you able to access it?

Comment: Both ways again  500 Internal Server Error appears

Comment: Its possible you have not configured your Apache properly `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. On line 503 make sure `httpd-vhosts.conf` this file is not comment. Line 243 & 244 has this directory `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: Everything is as you wrote.

Comment: Provide screenshot for Error 500. This error occurred on accessing `http://localhost` or `http:phalcon`

Comment: Does not matter how you write path the error 500 appears  http://imgur.com/TXZ2LZb

Comment: Check your log file what does it says?

Comment: phalcon error logs says: [Sat Dec 05 20:05:34.837116 2015] [core:error] [pid 5992:tid 1640] [client 127.0.0.1:50024] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: do you have any `.htaccess` in your directory or using `RewriteCond` ?

Comment: In htdocs I do not have any but in phalcon I got two(/phalcon and /public). They were in course which I linked above http://www.phalcon.pl/forum/tutoriale/hello-world/